# Extract tags from a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, split

I am stuck. Not that I'm a profi in regex, quite the contrary in fact. But I fail to solve a seemingly obvious task.

The original string:

```
tag:tag1; tag:tag2;tag:tag3; tag:tag4
```

I need to extract tags, i.e. everything between "tag:" and the next semicolon (or the end of line for the last tag). The best I could derive so far is this

```
{tag:(?P<tag>[^;]+)(;|$)}i
```

I.e. start with "tag:", then allow any symbols except for semicolon, and then finish with a semicolon or end of line. And do case-insensitive matching. But with both `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`, I only get the first tag with this regex :(

An alternative (but without loops) method to achieve what I want—an array of tag strings—with PHP also counts.

Comment: Your regex and `preg_match_all()` work just fine.

Comment: I've failed to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Cant you get rid of the tag: and then use explode(";",$string);  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here:

```
$text = 'tag:tag1; tag:tag2;tag:tag3; tag:tag4';
preg_match_all('{tag:(?P<tag>[^;]+)(;|$)}i', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches['tag']);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag1
    [1] => tag2
    [2] => tag3
    [3] => tag4
)
```

Comment: Weird delimiters `{` and `}`. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Paul, awesome, thanks a lot! I was trying using http://preg_match_all.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and somehow it didn't work properly.

Comment: @Rudie: Why don't you like my delimiters? :) I couldn't find anything less probable inside usual language.

Comment: @texnic Are you kidding? I'm in love with your delimiters! I love curly, symmetric delimiters. You can wake me up anytime for those big round curly puppies. I've just never known it's possible. I've always thought the start and end delim had to be identical: `~..~i`, my fav `#..#i` and of course `/../i` etc.

Comment: @Rudie: glad to contribute to at least someone's knowledge here, neighbour! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using str_replace() + explode(), like Jelle Keizer suggested.

```
   <?php
    $text = 'tag:tag1; tag:tag2;tag:tag3; tag:tag4';  

    $text = str_replace(array('tag:', ' '),array('', ''), $text);
    $array = explode(';', $text);

    var_dump($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag1
    [1] => tag2
    [2] => tag3
    [3] => tag4
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I prefer regex since it makes sure, e.g. spaces in tags are possible.